# Is $b$ in the drag force formula $F=-bv$ constant for a certain medium and object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, drag, viscosity

I heard that $F=-bv$, where $F$ is the [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) force, $b$ is the damping coefficient, and $v$ is the velocity of an object, can be used to calculate the drag force exerted on an object moving at a moderate velocity.

1. What range is this moderate velocity referring to?
2. Does $b$ in the drag force formula $F=-bv$ have to be constant for a certain medium and object?
3. If the answer to question 2 is a "yes" my question is: should $b$ not vary in the damped oscillation formula $x(t)=Ae^{-b/2m}cos(ωt)$? It sounds counterintuitive that $b$ has to be constant in that formula.
   I've done an experiment where I changed the value of spring constant in spring-mass systems damped in water, and my results (which seem to be precise) show different values of $b$ for different spring constants.

Comment: I think what you are referring to as an ideal viscous damper, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not referring to some *absolute* range of velocities, rather it means the flow of fluid around the object is *laminar flow*.

We can establish whether or not the flow is laminar by computing the so-called dimensionless number $\mathbf{Re}$, i.e. *[Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number)*:

$$\mathbf{Re}=\frac{vD}{\nu}$$

where:

- $v$ is the velocity
- $D$ a characteristic dimension of the object (like its diameter)
- $\nu$ the kinematic viscosity of the fluid

Laminar flow occurs for $\mathbf{Re}<2300$ and turbulent flow for $\mathbf{Re}>2900$ (in between these numbers is the so-called 'transitional regime'). In the laminar regime, viscous drag forces are said to dominate $F$ and in the turbulent regime inertial forces dominate it.

In the case or turbulent flow the drag force is of the form:

$$F=-cv^2$$

so the velocity dependence is on the **square** of the velocity.

2. In the either laminar or turbulent regime $b$ and $c$ resp. are considered constant and invariant to $v$.
3. I've not checked your formula ($x(t)=Ae^{-b/2m}\cos(ωt)$) but why does it "*sounds counterintuitive that b has to be constant in that formula*"? As stated above: in the relatively narrow velocity interval (laminar flow!) $b$ should be constant.